# DataTable is not a function on Liferay 7

Tags: java, jquery, web-applications, datatable, liferay

**This is my current code on `liferay`:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

    <html>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    });

    </script>

    </html>
```

**I did not import any jquery reference because by default it is in `liferay` 7 already (tested with a jQuery function) so i just copied the `datatable` CDN on to my `liferay`.**

However it says that datatable is not a function..could i been referencing the datatables wrongly? (unlikely) or i will need a reference to jQuery again? (tried but may cause conflict).

*p/s the same code is able to run on jsfiddle and displaying the datatable*
  [>>jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdy9h4w0/21/)

Answer (score 2):

To use this jQuery plugin, you need to deactive the Liferay JS Loader, as explained here: https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/using-external-libraries.

In your case, your code to import the DataTables JS could be:

```
<script>
    Liferay.Loader.define._amd = Liferay.Loader.define.amd;
    Liferay.Loader.define.amd = false;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    Liferay.Loader.define.amd = Liferay.Loader.define._amd;
</script>
```

You should add the snippet above at the bottom of your custom theme (in `portal_normal.ftl` file, just before the `body` closing tag).

Comment: where do you add these? i added on top of my existing codes but still doesnt work..

Comment: @Liferayer, I have just updated my answer to precise this.

Comment: i have done as told to add the snippet of codes into portal_normal and removing my existing import in my original code but still unable to display datatable....am i missing out some steps like restarting the server etc since portal_normal is part of the server's file????

Comment: You just need to redeploy your custom theme project (where you have just added the snippet) and your custom portlet (where I assume your HTML is located). What is the result now ? What do you see ? What error is printed on the console ?

Comment: The same problem...Datatable is not a function.. i have redeployed everything after adding the code snippets..

Comment: Do i have to Configuring Libraries to Support UMD too? extracted from the link that you provided? i am confuse at what it does..

Answer (score 0):

Liferay 7.0 DXP uses an AMD loader for loading javascript files.

if you are loading interdependent js modules then you need to disable it.

there are many ways to do it.

1. Configuration (for 7.0 DXP SP2+ or Liferay 7.0 CE GA4+)
   you can simply open the administration sidebar and select Control Panel > Configuration > System Settings > Foundation > JavaScript Loader > Uncheck Expose Global.
2. From Code.

   ```
   <script>
      Liferay.Loader.define._amd = Liferay.Loader.define.amd;
      Liferay.Loader.define.amd = false;
   </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        Liferay.Loader.define.amd = Liferay.Loader.define._amd;
    </script>
   ```

   if this code is not working then try this one.

   ```
   <script>
        define._amd = define.amd;
        define.amd = false;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        define.amd = define._amd;
    </script>
   ```

3.Alternatively, you can fix this by manually editing your JS file.
Change any text in js library with.

```
typeof define == 'function'
```

To:

```
false && typeof define == 'function'
```